# ControlTemplate Binding TextBox inside ErrorTemplate

Tags: c#, wpf, binding

My problem is, that I don't get the ToolTip Text thrown by the SetterException of my binding object.

I have a ControlTemplate like this:

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="textBoxErrorTemplate" >
    <Grid Margin="-15,5,0,0" ToolTip="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent},Path=(Validation.Errors)[0].ErrorContent}">
        <Ellipse StrokeThickness="0" Fill="Red" Width="{TemplateBinding FontSize}" Height="{TemplateBinding FontSize}" />
        <TextBlock Text="!" FontSize="{TemplateBinding FontSize}" FontWeight="Bold" Foreground="White" HorizontalAlignment="Center"  />                               
    </Grid>
</ControlTemplate>
```

I also tried

```
ToolTip="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self},Path=(Validation.Errors)[0].ErrorContent}"
ToolTip="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type TextBox}},Path=(Validation.Errors)[0].ErrorContent}"
```

My TextBox looks like this:

```
<TextBox Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Name="tbMin" SourceUpdated="tb_SourceUpdated" Validation.ErrorTemplate="{StaticResource textBoxErrorTemplate}"/>
```

I'm binding the data source in code like this:

```
Binding bindMinString = new Binding("MinString");
        bindMinString.Source = curStep;
        bindMinString.NotifyOnSourceUpdated = true;
        bindMinString.ValidatesOnExceptions = true;
        bindMinString.UpdateSourceTrigger = UpdateSourceTrigger.PropertyChanged;
        tbMin.SetBinding(TextBox.TextProperty, bindMinString);
```

The template seems to work (I see the ellipse with the "!"), but I don't see my exception message.

Comment: For the `Binding` in your `ErrorTemplate`, try using `{RelativeSource Self}` instead of `{RelativeSource TemplatedParent}`.

Comment: I just updated what I also tried, and didn't work. So doesn't your idea.

Comment: I don't see `<AdornedElementPlaceholder/>`.

Comment: Why should I put one? As I said, I can see the ellipse on the correct position. If I use a static text, I can see the ToolTip as well. Just the binding is not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The DataContext cannot flow down from the visual tree into an `ErrorTemplate`. So using `RelativeSource` or `ElementName` to target some visual element outside won't work here. The only link here is the `AdornedElementPlaceholder`, even when you don't need to add it, you can set `Visibility` to `Collapsed`. At least it's the best way to target the element having the ErrorTemplate applied. It has a property called `AdornedElement` and this is the access point you need. Here is the working code:

```
<Grid Margin="-15,5,0,0" 
      ToolTip="{Binding AdornedElement.(Validation.Errors)[0].ErrorContent,
                        ElementName=a}">
    <AdornedElementPlaceholder Name="a" Visibility="Collapsed"/>
    <Ellipse StrokeThickness="0" Fill="Red" 
       Width="{TemplateBinding FontSize}" Height="{TemplateBinding FontSize}" />
    <TextBlock Text="!" FontSize="{TemplateBinding FontSize}" FontWeight="Bold" 
        Foreground="White" HorizontalAlignment="Center"  />
</Grid>
```

***UPDATE***:

I've just found another more direct solution. In fact the implicit `DataContext` inside `ErrorTemplate` is set to a `ReadonlyObservableCollection<ValidationError>` which is the value of `Validation.Errors`, so the code can be much simpler like this:

```
<Grid Margin="-15,5,0,0" 
      ToolTip="{Binding [0].ErrorContent}">
    <Ellipse StrokeThickness="0" Fill="Red" 
       Width="{TemplateBinding FontSize}" Height="{TemplateBinding FontSize}" />
    <TextBlock Text="!" FontSize="{TemplateBinding FontSize}" FontWeight="Bold" 
        Foreground="White" HorizontalAlignment="Center"  />
</Grid>
```

Comment: Odd, the MSDN sample I consulted suggested that `Validation.Errors` from the adorned element is applied to the `TemplatedAdorner` as well, but a quick test with Snoop indicates this is not the case.  Good catch.

Comment: @MikeStrobel here the `Validation.Errors` is still of the `TextBox` (which is accessed via `AdornedElement` property of `AdornedElementPlaceholder`. I think that property is designed for this kind of scenario.